# How do I speed up a WordPress website in terms of SEO?

Tags: wordpress, redirection-wordpress-plugin

I Choose WordPress for blogs and news related. But my website load speed is very low, It takes higher time related to SEO friendliness This is my site [althyper.com](https://althyper.com/)

I need To reduce time to make it SEO friendly Please give some suggestions

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions on https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Falthyper.com%2F
For example, to "Serve images in next-gen formats" I use a plugin called *WebP Converter for Media*. Also consider using plugin called *Hummingbird* for caching and compressing. But it seems you already get score of 100 for desktop. That's pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

This is a loaded question. Did you create the website yourself? If so, you should be thinking about optimisation while you're developing.

If not, then you're going to have to rely on a combination of plugins,  reliable hosting and common sense.

Some things to consider:

1. Find a plugin that offloads all local assets (images, JS files etc) to a CDN, and also minifies CSS and JS ([WP Rocket](https://wp-rocket.me/) might be the way to go).
2. Use a theme that supports lazy loading.
3. Use fast, reliable hosting (WP Engine for example).
4. Keep your database lean - don't keep thousands of revisions if you don't need them.
5. Disable all unnecessary plugins.
6. Edit your wp-config.php file to allow adequate PHP memory allowance, For example:

   define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');

This should improve things. Take some benchmarks [here](https://pagespeed.web.dev/), [here](https://yellowlab.tools/) and [here](https://gtmetrix.com/) before you do any of this so you have before/after values to compare.

Good luck.